# How Do I Delete A SSIS Log Configuration in SSDT

Tags: visual-studio, logging, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2017

There doesn't seem to be a way to delete certain configurations/connections in SSDT, at least not through Visual Studio.

For example,  when I create a text file connection for logging I don't see where to  edit nor delete it later.  I can only create a new one and assign it to a provider.

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connections created can be deleted from the connection manager panel found on the bottom of the control flow. Since each connection is related to a connection manager.

[image]

Comment: @TrevorReid i added a screenshot

Comment: I wonder why they don't appear with the other connection managers in the solution explorer. @Hadi

Comment: The connection managers shown in the solution explorer are the project connection manager which can be used in multiple packages. It doesn't contains the connection managers created at the package level.

Comment: @TrevorReid feel free to accept the answer if it solved the issue. Good Luck